# 'close’ was not declared in this scope in building Opencv

Tags: opencv, gcc, cmake, g++, cygwin

I am building Opencv in Windows using Cygwin and Cmake.
My Cygwin has gcc/g++ version 5.4.
When I build Opencv, I have error as

```
/cygdrive/c/Softwares/opencv-2.4.13/modules/core/src/system.cpp:526:13: error:                  close’ was not declared in this scope
     close(fd);
```

Is it because of gcc/g++ version doesn't match to Opencv?

Comment: usually it is not wise to build opencv on windows with something else that Microsoft C++ compiler...
Anyway, you did not provides enough information.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi what information do you need? I just encountered that error.

Comment: The error message looks like compiler interpret spaces before `close` as a part of the function name. Check that these spaces are common spaces (with 0x20 code) and not an language-specific ones.

Comment: @Tsyvarev how to check? You meant go to the source?

Comment: Yes, check the source code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev how to check common spaces (with 0x20 code)? I just backspace to delete all spaces.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I deleted all spaces with backspace key till the end of previous line. But still have error.

Comment: As mentioned by @HumamHelfawi, it is not wised to compile Opencv with something else. I used Visual Studio and no issues. If not need to modify all conflicts manually.